# How can I implement a database TableView like thing in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, sql, relational-database, boost

How can I implement a TableView like thing in C++?

I want to emulating a tiny relation database like thing in C++. I have data tables, and I want to transform it somehow, so I need a TableView like class. I want filtering, sorting, freely add and remove items and transforming (ex. view as UPPERCASE and so on). The whole thing is inside a GUI application, so datatables and views are attached to a GUI (or HTML or something).

So how can I identify an item in the view? How can I signal it when the table is changed? Is there some design pattern for this?

Here is a simple table, and a simple data item:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>

using boost::multi_index_container;
using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct Data
{
  Data() {}
  int id;
  std::string name;
};

struct row{};
struct id{};
struct name{};

typedef boost::multi_index_container<
  Data,
  indexed_by<
    random_access<tag<row> >,
    ordered_unique<tag<id>, member<Data, int, &Data::id> >,
    ordered_unique<tag<name>, member<Data, std::string, &Data::name> >
  >
> TDataTable;

class DataTable
{
public:
  typedef Data item_type;
  typedef TDataTable::value_type value_type;
  typedef TDataTable::const_reference const_reference;
  typedef TDataTable::index<row>::type TRowIndex;
  typedef TDataTable::index<id>::type TIdIndex;
  typedef TDataTable::index<name>::type TNameIndex;
  typedef TRowIndex::iterator iterator;

  DataTable() :
    row_index(rule_table.get<row>()),
    id_index(rule_table.get<id>()),
    name_index(rule_table.get<name>()),
    row_index_writeable(rule_table.get<row>())
  {
  }

  TDataTable::const_reference operator[](TDataTable::size_type n) const
  { return rule_table[n]; }

  std::pair<iterator,bool> push_back(const value_type& x)
  { return row_index_writeable.push_back(x); }

  iterator erase(iterator position)
  { return row_index_writeable.erase(position); }

  bool replace(iterator position,const value_type& x)
  { return row_index_writeable.replace(position, x); }

  template<typename InputIterator> void rearrange(InputIterator first)
  { return row_index_writeable.rearrange(first); }

  void print_table() const;

  unsigned size() const
  { return row_index.size(); }

  TDataTable rule_table;
  const TRowIndex& row_index;
  const TIdIndex& id_index;
  const TNameIndex& name_index;
private:
  TRowIndex& row_index_writeable;
};

class DataTableView
{
  DataTableView(const DataTable& source_table) {}
  // How can I implement this?
  // I want filtering, sorting, signaling upper GUI layer, and sorting, and ...
};

int main()
{
  Data data1;
  data1.id = 1;
  data1.name = "name1";
  Data data2;
  data2.id = 2;
  data2.name = "name2";

  DataTable table;
  table.push_back(data1);
  DataTable::iterator it1 = table.row_index.iterator_to(table[0]);
  table.erase(it1);
  table.push_back(data1);
  Data new_data(table[0]);
  new_data.name = "new_name";
  table.replace(table.row_index.iterator_to(table[0]), new_data);
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < table.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << table[i].name << std::endl;

#if 0
  // using scenarios:
  DataTableView table_view(table);
  table_view.fill_from_source(); // synchronization with source
  table_view.remove(data_item1); // remove item from view
  table_view.add(data_item2); // add item from source table
  table_view.filter(filterfunc); // filtering
  table_view.sort(sortfunc); // sorting

  // modifying from source_able, hot to signal the table_view?
  // FYI: Table view is atteched to a GUI item
  table.erase(data);
  table.replace(data);
#endif

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which GUI framework are you using? If you use QT, you may solve this with the tools provided by the QT lib, and not with boost.

Comment: Gtk is used now, and some kind of HTML is planned but not selected which one

Answer (score 1):

If your using the QT SDK you can use the [QTableView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html). You could also look at the source code for QTableView to get an idea how to build your own TableView class.